# Is it Safe to Rely on Gmail API to Reward Users for Placing Orders on Merchant Sites?

Tags: email, account-security, gmail, email-spoofing, fraud

I have an application that rewards users for placing orders with certain merchants. In order to verify that the order was actually placed and delivered, a user is required to grant us read access to a new [Gmail Inbox](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36894292) that is created and shared with us for this purpose. This allows us to read order confirmation emails, shipping confirmation emails and for some merchants the delivery email. If the order was canceled then we'd be able to read the order cancellation email as well. The goal is to minimize the risk of a user placing an order on a merchant site and then canceling it without us knowing about it. I have a few doubts about this approach:

1. Can a user spoof the contents of an email to make it look like an order or delivery confirmation email was received from a merchant when in fact wasn't?
2. Can a user delete an order cancellation email from his inbox before we get a chance to read it? If yes, is there a to detect that an email was deleted?
3. I realize a user can revoke access to his inbox at any time, add or remove emails and then re-grant access. However, I don't think this would be a problem because should we detect that access was revoked at any time between the order and delivery we can reverse any rewards linked to those orders. Is this correct?
4. Are there any other risks associated with this approach?
5. Would the same apply to other email providers such as Outlook (Microsoft), Apple and Yahoo Mail?

We do have other ways of confirming orders but each approach has certain flaws and weaknesses. My goal is to understand the weakness of this approach (if any) and work with the strengths of each approach to eliminate or reduce the likelihood of fraud.

How reliable is this approach?

Comment: @schroeder Access to the data is in the subject's best interest because they would otherwise not reap the rewards of their actions. If I was able to request access to specific emails you could argue that requesting all emails would violate the regulations. But assuming this is not possible, then by definition we require access to all of the user's emails. But more importantly, what I think you (and others) are misunderstanding is that our users are already setting up a brand new email just for the purpose of using our service. By definition, it means we are only accessing the emails we require

Comment: Ah, your wording is unclear: "access to their". It's not "theirs", it's "shared". And you could have mentioned that a lot sooner in this process. Hence my "the customer base we're dealing with would be OK with sharing their inbox with us." -- this might need explanation. that I posted ***12 hours ago***

Comment: In fact, one could say that you misrepresented the situation entirely by making that comment. They "would not be OK with sharing" but rather, creating and sharing the new inbox is part of the process. or did you just think of this modification recently?

Comment: @schroeder Thanks for editing the OP-  it's definitely much clearer now. One thing I would emphasize is that when you say they will "share" access with us you mean API access (not like sharing the password). Perhaps this is obvious in context of the question, just making sure that's what you meant. Regarding your second question (attack) I've mentioned this in at least 2-3 comments already. I did not just think of it. It would have been the default action for the overwhelming majority (if not all) of our users anyhow. Perhaps now I would just try to enforce this practice better.

Comment: No, you've hand-waved any objections away. That's *not* adressing them.

Comment: You are sharing the account. You both can access it. The customer owns it and controls it. **The privacy issue still exists, though.** If they use the email for purposes other than what you expect them to, you are still on the hook. You are borrowing Gmail Personal to manage email on your behalf and hoping that users abide by ***your*** terms and conditions over Gmail's. That's not reasonable and won't stand up if there is ever a problem.

Answer (score 6):

First, expecting the user to provide **full** access to their mail to you sounds like a terrible idea for me, since this gives you also access to all private or otherwise sensitive mails of the user. Even if there is no intention for misusing this on your side, it will be hard to prevent the misuse in the first place. You also will be a valuable target for attackers since they will get access to users mail boxes when hacking you. In addition this whole approach is limited to users of GMail, and for users of each other mail servers you have to need to explicitly extend your service. That said ...

> Can a user spoof contents of an email to make it look like an order or delivery confirmation email was received from a merchant when in fact wasn't?

This depends on a) how good you check and b) how good the senders mail infrastructure is setup. Creating spoofed mails is easy unless the sender explicitly protects against it with electronically signed mails, working DMARC or similar protections.

> Can a user delete an order cancellation email from his inbox before we get a chance to read it? If yes, is there a to detect that an email was deleted?

It is unclear how quick you get information about new mails. But the user might setup rules to automatically delete specific mails and can also setup the Trash to not preserve mails.

> Are there any other risks associated with this approach?

See my initial statements for this. Again, I find this a terrible idea both regarding privacy but also the users and yours security.

> Would the same apply to other email providers such as Outlook (Microsoft), Apple and Yahoo Mail?

Mostly yes. Not all of these allow granting access to the account to others though like GMail does. In this case you would need to know the users original credentials, which is even more privacy invasive and insecure, for example if the user reuses the same credentials to login into other services or sites.

---

Apart from all of this your approach is fragile. There is no common way to confirm orders or to confirm order cancellation. This means that you need to adapt your code of analyzing the mails to each merchant and that the code might break unexpectedly any time if the merchant changes something.  It might be much easier, less fragile, much harder to spoof, more secure and more privacy friendly if you have agreements with the merchants and get the information directly from these.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Regarding your first point, a good percentage of our users will actually be using a brand new email just to sign up on our site so the issue of us reading and misusing other private emails is not really a problem. In either case, full disclosure to user is always made so we won't be obtaining access without their explicit consent and understanding. I see you emphasized the word **full** - presumably we could only request access to read email from specific senders which would be enough. This would mitigate any privacy concerns.

Comment: @BradfordGriggs: *"presumably we could only request access to read email from specific senders which would be enough"* - I'm not sure that such feature is actually offered by GMail. It will definitely not offered by all mail providers you might want to use.

Comment: I'd walk away *instantly* if met by such terms. In addition, what about those who don't use gmail? It sounds like an *horrible* way to verify purchases. A better idea would be to get the order data, including cancellations, directly from the merchant.

Comment: @ _Steffen Ullrich @vidarlo Since email spoofing can be solved using DMARC as you suggested, it seems to me that the only real remaining problem is the fact that users can set filters that prevent certain emails from showing up in their inbox in the first place. Assuming I have a way to solve this, do you see any other problems with this method? (I'm not discussing the issue of user consent in this post, obviously this is something we will have to obtain and I'm willing to take the risk of some users "walking away" if they don't like it. My focus is whether the method is a reliable or not)

Comment: @BradfordGriggs: *"Since email spoofing can be solved using DMARC as you suggested,..."* - which need to be done be each merchant. And it need to be done, properly. The majority of domains have no DMARC implement and many have not done it strict and for many the underlying DKIM/SPF is too wide or too insecure configured.

Comment: @BradfordGriggs: *"... do you see any other problems with this method?  ..."* - I've mentioned many problems in my answer, covering a spectrum of security, privacy but also reliability of your method. And I find these  already hard to solve. I don't know why you need even more problems. Like I said and like vidario said in his post: working together with the merchant directly to get these information is much better.

Comment: I'm not seeing the obvious bypass of the Gmail inbox entirely by a 3rd party email system as the other major flaw in the approach. I can set up a Gmail account and access it from a different email system and filter for convenience there. No filters would exist in the Gmail system but it could also hide cancelled orders. This design is on the wrong side of the leverage. The end user has all control, you have none.

Comment: @schroeder Thanks for your input. "I can set up a Gmail account and access it from a different email system and filter for convenience there" Can you please elaborate? What do you mean by setting up 3rd party email system and filtering emails from there?

Comment: @SteffenUllrich The flaws I am looking for are with the reliability of the method. Much of the focus here is on the perceived privacy issues. One thing I think everyone is misunderstanding about the service is that customers of our service are likely to sign up for the service with a brand new email address anyhow, which is intended to be used exclusively for this service. We won't be accessing anything other than the order data we need. I appreciate your concern for user privacy. However, I'm afraid there's a basic misconception how the service works.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich I do appreciate your analysis regarding the the flaws with the actual approach. Regarding the user setting up filters to reject and delete certain emails it seems to be possible to retrieve user set filters using Gmail API so I don't see this being much of an issue. Also, keep in mind, many of the merchants we are working with send actual delivery confirmation emails. For those merchants we don't have to worry about the user deleting the cancellation emails as we would not authorize the reward until we detect the delivery confirmation email.

Comment: @BradfordGriggs: Again: *"you need to adapt your code of analyzing the mails to each merchant and that the code might break unexpectedly any time if the merchant changes something"*. Again: to defend against spoofing merchants need to properly implement DMARC etc and most don't have this. On top of that: how you deal with the cases where the item was delivered but then returned? I fully agree with schroeder that you should not try to salvage your idea somehow but fully rethink your approach. There are too many obvious problems with it and there might be more problems once you implement it.

Comment: @BradfordGriggs I can answer as simply as "Thunderbird" or further and saying IMAP, or as far as setting up my own API access.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich **Issue 1**: Our code base is already setup to analyze emails from each merchant and has a sophisticated way of adapting to changes. Probably not perfect, but it's pretty good so I'm not concerned of this too much.  **Issue 2**: I've checked and it seems that at least half of the fortune 500 companies implement DMARC  - I believe all of the retailers we plan on working with do. **Issue 3**: We already have a way of dealing with returns so I'm not concerned about this in the slightest. So from a purely reliability perspective what else must I salvage?

Comment: @BradfordGriggs: *"I believe all of the retailers we plan on working with do."* - don't believe but check. And check that they do it correctly, i.e. strict policies, strict DKIM headers without too much way of header spoofing etc. *"Probably not perfect, ..."* - that's what I mean, the basic approach is fragil. It will never be perfect. Can you really estimate the actual risk of distinguishing between real orders, faked orders, cancellations you might not see ...  . Also, the risks of simply deleting cancellations with IMAP or API by the user still exists.

Answer (score 4):

Your goal here is obviously to verify that the customer indeed purchased whatever merchant sells, and not merely sent a order, which was later cancelled.

First of all, sending fake e-mails is a rather trivial task. Second, you're casting a wider net than needed; you don't need access to users e-mail account. You just need a confirmation that they ordered this. You also open yourself up to race conditions, where the customer may add filters that deletes the email before you get to see it.

Work with the merchant. The proper solution is some sort of connection to the merchant, either through batch reports at given intervals, or an API, or even web hooks, that the merchants software calls when a new order is received and cancelled.

This way you will know the order status from a source you trust; the vendor. The customer can't stop the batch report, API or whatever you use to transmit the data - so there's no need to trust the customer anymore. In addition, you don't gain access to any more data than you need to your task: verify that the customer purchased something.

If this is impossible, you could ask the user to sign up with the merchant with a e-mail address you control. Generate an address per user, and forward all incoming e-mail to the user while checking it for whatever you want.

This way the customer can't filter mails before you see them, and you can't read all the e-mail of customers.

A sidenote: As your customer base grows, you'll be a fat, juicy, target: verified human-operated gmail accounts used for ecommerce... I hope you have world class security! In addition, I'd check carefully with regulatory agencies before embarking on this.

Comment: @ _vidarlo working with the merchant is obviously not an option in this case, otherwise I would never propose this solution. Additionally, of the customer base we're dealing with would be OK with sharing their inbox with us. What I've derived from your response regarding the actual question is **1)** that it is trivial for customers to send fake emails (this was addressed by @Steffen Ullrich and can be solved usingg DMARC ) **2)** it is possible for the customer to delete a cancellation email before we get a chance to read it. If we ping his email very frequently this should also be solvable.

Comment: Perhaps the only real problem with this approach that remains is the fact that users can set filters that prevent emails from showing up in their inbox in the first place.

Comment: See my edit. I proposed a less invasive solution that might actually scale.

Comment: @BradfordGriggs "the customer base we're dealing with would be OK with sharing their inbox with us." -- this might need explanation. If you have a pre-existing relationship with the customer base, then there may be other avenues to take.

Comment: @schroeder I like your suggestion of providing each customer with an email address we control. Ultimately, I think it involves too much work to be practical.  One thing I think everyone is misunderstanding about the service is that customers of our service are likely to sign up for the service with a brand new email address anyhow, which is intended to be used exclusively for this service. We won't be accessing anything other than the order data we need. I appreciate everyone's concern for user privacy. However, I'm afraid there's a basic misconception how the service works.

Comment: @BradfordGriggs It doesn't involve any work; such things can be automated - and probably *far* easier than the work required to automate inbox access for google. In addition, I wouldn't bet on google not shutting you down when you hit a certain threshold of accounts you access...

Comment: @vidarlo there are existing APIs that automate access to Gmail Inbox (and other email providers). Perhaps an alternative approach to creating a new email for each user is to ask the end user to forward all incoming mail from supported merchants to an email address we control. However, I believe that DMARC no longer works with forwarded mail so you come back to the original problem of email spoofing.

Comment: You still have to implement the API in your software. That sounds harder than whipping up a catch all e-mail address and checking who it's destined for and do whatever processing you want. In addition, you don't risk being a fat juicy target for attackers. In short: your proposal is way worse than what I would dream up if I was tasked with thinking of a wild Rube Goldberg-scheme for doing this. It's crazy. Listen to the expirience that tells you that it's silly.

Comment: @vidarlo "whipping up a catch all e-mail address" is not an option as the users need a Gmail or Microsoft email to use our service. What I think you (and others) are misunderstanding is that our users are already setting up a brand new email just for the purpose of using our service. How is that different than us generating a email on behalf of each user? We have access to the exact same data whether we ask the user to setup a brand new email address for the purpose of using our service or we set it up for them. Please see my previous comments and you will see I mentioned this multiple times.